# Throttle asynchronous Mono by number of concurrent tasks (not time-based)

Tags: java, project-reactor

Say I have a method which takes a parameter and returns a `Mono<Integer>` that asynchronously completes. For example:

```
Random random = new Random();
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(16);

Mono<Integer> fetch(String a) {
  return Mono.create(em -> {
    scheduledExecutorService.schedule(() -> em.next(a + " result"), 
      10 + random.nextInt(50), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  });
}
```

Say I have a `Flux<String>` that I can feed into the `fetch` method above and that can have a lot of elements.

Is there a way I can ensure that the method gets called in parallel, but limit the number of concurrent calls to a predefined number?

E.g. 4 in the above example, while I have 16 available threads - so I always keep 12 spare from this perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by "feed into", you mean you are using `flux.flatMap(this::fetch)`,
then you can set the flatMap concurrency by calling `flux.flatMap(this::fetch, 4)` instead.

Also, your code has two compile errors:

1. the return type of fetch `Mono<Integer>` does not match the type of item you are giving to the sink (`a + " result"`).  I assume you meant `Mono<String>`
2. MonoSink does not have a `.next` method. I assume you meant `.success`

Given all of that, here's an example:

```java
    private Flux<String> fetchAll() {
        return Flux.range(0, 50)
                .map(i -> Integer.toString(i))
                .flatMap(this::fetch, 4);

    }

    private Mono<String> fetch(String a) {
        return Mono.create(em ->
                scheduledExecutorService.schedule(() -> em.success(a + " result"),
                        10 + random.nextInt(50), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        );
    }
```